# Two Pane layout + DrawerLayout: replace main content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I have a DrawerLayout with three sections: one of them is a two pane layout implemented like the android studio template, so two fragment, one next to the other, contained in a LinearLayout. Here is the layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:id="@+id/twoPaneLayut"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/alarm_list_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/alarm_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111" />
```

Now, the other sections are composed by a single Fragment so I was trying to replace the main content of the external FrameLayout with a FragmentTransaction.

The problem is that the inner LinearLayout obviously is not removed.

So what is the best strategy to follow? removing programmatically the LinearLayout? Setting its visibilty to GONE?

Comment: Does it work with LinearLayout for the 2 panels instead of the FrameLayout?

Comment: With LinearLayout it works! but now the problem is when I want to switch back to the first section. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you need to know. But if you hide one linear layout, the other should fill the screen. So if you need to switch between full screen and half and half that is one option.

Comment: I understood that the common way to implement a DrawerLayout is to have an Activity hosting a fragment (in a single FrameLayout) and, to switch between the drawer sections, replacing the current fragment with another using a FragmentTransaction. This is what I need, but as you see in my layout, it is not applicable because in one section I have a multiple Fragments.

Comment: There are a few options you have. I'll add your options to the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FrameLayout` will not work with `weightSum` it is by design meant to fill up your layout. Try using a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` instead.

Secondly, when it comes to swapping all your content, you have a few options.

**Option 1**
Use one `FrameLayout`, for your 2 panel layout create a `Fragment` that contains 2 Fragments. Yes, you can have `Fragment`s within `Fragment`s.

In this scenario, your `Activity`'s layout will look more like the implementation that Google recommends and it is your fragments layout that will contain the 2 panel layout.

**Option 2**
You can swap out one of the `LinearLayout`s for your fragment and hide the other `LinearLayout`. There is no reason you can only swap a `FrameLayout` for a fragment, you should be able to swap out a `LinearLayout` for a `Fragment` as well.

**Option 3**
The `DrawerLayout` implementation is just a recommendation. You can move the layout for your drawer into a fragment and use a different `Activity` for your different layouts. To be clear, instead of a `ListView` for your drawer, you will have a fragment. In this scenario, put all the code to add the toggle controls in a helper class so you can easily reuse it, your drawer view will be in a fragment and hence it will be easier to include in multiple activities.

I've included an example of how to do this, because you need to wrap your navigation drawer fragment in a frame layout and give the frame layout the `layout_gravity` property otherwise the fragment will fill up the whole screen and not close.

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_container"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.alimuzaffar.myapp.fragment.NavigationMenuFragment" />
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The code for the toggle helper can be something like the `setupNavigationDrawer()` method below. Just call this code from the `onCreate()` of any activity you want to have the navigation drawer.

```
public static void setupNavigationDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call
                                                                // to
                                                                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call
                                                                // to
                                                                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think that the first option is the more polish, I'll try and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I would take the first option. However i would also integrate the fragment idea from #3 into your project as it leads to cleaner activity code. Please accept the answer if you are happy with it.